# OTA gives a menu with option "Open in 'App Store' ", but does not install OTA from OwnCloud

Tags: ios, iphone, ota, owncloud

OTA gives a menu with option "Open in 'App Store' ", but does not install OTA from OwnCloud

I have read Apple Ad hoc and Enterprise distribution documents.  I referenced StackOverFlow posting 
[wireless iphone app distribution - problem with itms-services protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695180/wireless-iphone-app-distribution-problem-with-itms-services-protocol) .   I am using OwnCloud as server to distribute Ad hoc iOS 7.1 apps.  When I download the Index.html with

```
<a href = “itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://owncloud-myserver.net/mydirectory/myplist.plist”> Install iOS app</a>
```

I get a action sheet menu that shows the above URL and options to 'Open in “AppStore”, copy or cancel.

OwnCloud is running on an Apache server so I have updated the Mime types as suggested in StackOverFlow posting

[Ad-hoc distribution fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495469/ad-hoc-distribution-fail)

When I click the option “Open inApp Store”, nothing happens and app does not install.

What prompts should I receive if install would run as expected?  Any suggestions to help trouble-shoot this issue are appreciated.

Updated with key contents from my plist

```
<key>url</key>
      <string>https://owncloud-myserver.net/index.php/apps/files?dir=/mydirectory/myAdApp.ipa</string>
```

Comment: Is the space in `url= https` intentional or a copy/paste error?

Comment: Thanks it was a typo.  I corrected it in posting.

Comment: Include the contents of your `myplist.plist` file.

Comment: Any updates on this? Was the issue solved?

Comment: @mnickv31 Yes...problem was Owncloud URL was going to logon page.  For OTA to work once on SSl [https] website...page access must be direct without logon layer first.  apologies for delayed response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Owncloud URL was going to logon page.  For OTA to work on SSl [https] website...web page URL must be direct without logon layer first.

Answer (score 0):

We've had similar problems when old versions of the application, signed with outdated provisioning profiles, were still on the device. Manually deleting the application and/or profiles seems to fix it.